# JavaScriptSerializer How to Deserialize an identifier with space

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, javascriptserializer

I am having exactly the same problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565464/javascriptserializer-deserialize-an-identifier-with-space but as no one answered thought i'd try again,

API created by someone else in the form of

```
[{"AdvertId":"1234567","Price Original":"500","Sold":"False"}]
```

Application already uses a JavascriptSerilalization to populate the named properties on many other API's so do not want to change that really, but my class to hold this data can not have a property with a space in it "Price Original", and this can't be removed or replaced with an _ or something. Are there any methods that can be called to translate the string to something different?

Is there any solution to this or have I got to use JSON.net to deserialize, was some bits on DataContracts I read up on and these might be able to help but I can't seems to find out how to get this to work for my code, and would be nice to know that is possible without investigation this path.

Many thanks in advance

Sample Class

```
Class Sample
{
    public int AdvertId { get; set; }
    public string Price Original { get; set; }
    public bool Sold { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to create this class in .NET? AFAIK your solution with class like this will not compile at all.

Comment: One solution is to write your own JavascriptConverterClass http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx and handle the space scenario by removing or replacing it with an underscore during deserialization.

Comment: Hello Alex yes I know the class will not compile, was just example to highlight the "Price Original" property that is the issue.... ok looking into evasilchenko ty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use built-in types, but you'll need to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead of `JavaScriptSerializer`, and add the appropriate `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes - the implementation is a bit different, but still pretty straightforward.

One thing - your `Sold` property is boolean, but your JSON sample has a string there - booleans are valid JSON types, so you can remove the quotes.

Some working code:

JSON:

```
[{"AdvertId":"1234567","Price Original":"500","Sold":false}]
```

C#:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Sample[]));
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSON))) {
    Sample[] s = (Sample[])ser.ReadObject(ms);
}

[DataContract]
public class Sample {
    [DataMember]
    public int AdvertId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Price Original")]
    public string PriceOriginal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Sold { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Excellent Joe this looks so far to have done the trick so thank you for pointing  me in the right direction :)